# Sort large amount of data in the cloud?

Tags: sorting, cloud, distributed

Given a cloud storage folder with say 1PB of data in it, what would be the quickest way to sort all of that data? It's easy to sort small chunks of it, but then merging them into a larger sorted output will take longer since at some point a single process will have to merge the whole thing. I would like to avoid this, and have a fully distributed solution, is there a way? If so, is there any implementation that would be suitable for using to sort data in S3?

Answer (score 2):

Since the amount of data you need to sort exceeds RAM (by a lot), the only reasonable way (to my knowledge) is to sort chunks first and then merge them together.

[Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) is the best way to accomplish this task.  You can sort separate chunks of data at the same time with parallel processes, which should speed up your sort.

The thing is, after you done sorting chunks, you don't have to have a *single* process doing all of merging, you can have several processes merging different chunks at the same time:

> This algorithm uses a parallel merge algorithm to not only parallelize the recursive division of the array, but also the merge operation. It performs well in practice when combined with a fast stable sequential sort, such as insertion sort, and a fast sequential merge as a base case for merging small arrays.

Here is a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) that gives a bit more info about Merge Algorithm (just in case).

Answer (score 0):

Bad news- you cannot avoid k-merge of multiple sorted files. 
Good thing is that you can do some operations in parallel.